# Is a soap request maintained open until return?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

If a make a soap webservice request from a client (android, desktop app, etc): is the connection alive and open as long as the webservice did not send the response?

Or does the webservice create a "new connection" for the response to the client?

Which one does apply to webservices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The response will return back over the same connection. Web Service calls are done over `HTTP` which uses persistent `TCP` connections. `HTTP1.1` requires the underlying connection to persist across requests. The next request would also reuse the underlying connection but that is not required or guaranteed